# How to retrieve db credentials using Spring Cloud Vault

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-vault-config

We have a spring-boot 2 application that connects to db2 database via DAOs.  The current application uses application.properties to store the credentials, like this:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:db2://127.0.0.1:50000/bcupload
spring.datasource.username=db2user
spring.datasource.password=mysecretpa$$
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
```

I would like to store username and password in Hashicorp Vault and retreive it at runtime using Spring Cloud Vault facilities.

I've examined this [example](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-vault/#initial) from Spring Guides but I'm not understanding what to do with these values I retrieve them from the Vault.  How do convert them to properties that Spring Boot uses when connecting to my db2 data source?

Comment: You're saying: as long as spring.datasource.username and spring.datasource.password key-value-pairs are in the vault and we point to that vault using bootstrap.yml, that Spring-boot will retrieve those properties at application startup and automatically use them in datasource creation?

Comment: We have another application that uses SpringBatch and SpringFramework modules.   How can we use Spring Cloud Vault module in that app?

Answer (score 1):

Add the same property in vault and connect to Vault with Spring-cloud-vault Library. Have all Vault related configurations in

> bootstrap.yml

Not required to convert that as a property. Above mentioned steps are enough